# Presenting or Pushing an embeded controller to top of stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, transition, uicontainerview

I have this problem where in a table view I have this container with a embedded VC in it. when I presse it I want that embedded controller to be pushed as top controller on the navigation stack or be able to present it modally. I tried a few thing and I am getting the error that I can not present an already active VC. SO I guess we need to free the VC from its container view and do some magic. any one as any pointer to doing any thing like this if it is possible.

Comment: Tried to present it and gave me the error that the view is already active int he container. I tried to push it, but the animations are coming out wrong. The goal was to mimic the Weather app expandable table, It worked great till I needed to add some presentation animation and I got some conflict the answer was to make that viewcontroller the top controller and not just a controller embedded in a table. But I am getting errors. So fare I solved my problem by dropping the tableview and just have some views pushing each others. I will post an app on what I tried to do.

Comment: Instead of trying the new ways to show the view, why don't you try to do something like "free the VC from its container view" ?

Comment: We basically ended up changing the entire view hierarchy.